# php to rename files in directory based on columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file, rename

I was wondering if anyone could help with this. Let' say I have a db with columns 'cust_id' and 'name'.
I want to rename 2000+ images in a directory to 'cust_id.jpg' from their existing 'name.jpg'.
Column 'name' contains all the image names in the folder and I want them renamed to their associated customer id #.

I'm pretty certain this can be done w/ php/mysql but my knowledge of php is very limited and I wouldn't know where to start writing this. I realise I would have to create a recordset pulling the required data, read directory, loop through etc. but I this is just beyond my capabilities at the moment. Little help?

Thanks!

Comment: exactly.. you are on the right track.. Try something out.. and if it does not work.. post your code.. People here will definitely help you out fixing your code..

Comment: To simplify, I need to get the imagename from the db, match it with the physical file, and then rename that file to the cust_id # of that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.. assuming your table name is `tbl_customer` and you have your db connection settings in place

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_customer");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $name = $row['name'];
  $cust_id = $row['cust_id'];

  if(file_exists('path/to/your/image/directory/'.$name)){
    rename('path/to/your/image/directory/'.$name,'path/to/your/image/directory/'.$cust_id.".jpg");
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a recordset in DW (sorry lol) and attached the above to it, called in the browser and it loops through giving this error:          Warning: rename(testad/,testad/9235.jpg) [function.rename]: Invalid argument in /home/thepower/public_html/renametest.php on line 45    

I used this:

Comment: I should add that the line 45 error repeats on the page all through the column. I posted my code above but I guess I didn't wrap it right with the tags

Comment: I just looked in the folder and it seems as though it worked for about 80% of the files!
I think maybe the error was caused by empty db fields??

Comment: `Warning: rename(testad/,testad/9235.jpg)` that definitely means some fields are empty in DB

Comment: I definitely thank you! I never realized the script would be so simple. You have saved 2 people approx 2 days work manually renaming. The straggler files it left 'un-renamed' were old versions of ads whose names were not in the db. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Some details may be required for a good response. Sitll I'm giving a try to help you. I'm assuming table name etc for now. You can use your names. Also I'm assuming each customer has only one image.

```
UPDATE `customer_images`
SET `name` = CONCAT(`cust_id`,".jpg")
```

Here `cust_id` is the column name of customer id

Let me know if the assumptions are not correct or the SQL did not worked.

Comment: That's exactly what I'll be doing after I figure out how to rename all the files - or removing the column completely and hardcoding. Doing this I can delete 11 columns in my db!

Comment: Yes, I knew that would work. That's why I edited and added the .jpg there. For that I needed to confirm if all pics have .jpg extension. Now the problem is solved. Thats good!